# What happens to thread local variables when the thread is terminated?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, concurrency

I have a component that publishes messages to RabbitMQ.
In order to avoid blocking when sending messages I created a thread pool using [ruby-concurrency](http://ruby-concurrency.github.io/concurrent-ruby/file.thread_pools.html). The thread pool implementation has a parameter that controls when the thread will be terminated if it's idle for too long.

Since [channels cannot be shared](http://rubybunny.info/articles/concurrency.html#sharing_channels_between_threads) in Bunny I initialized them as thread local variables.

Do I have a memory leak? 
Will the channels go out of scope when the thread terminates after being idle for the configured amount of time?
Should I be using ruby-concurrency's [ThreadLocalVar](http://ruby-concurrency.github.io/concurrent-ruby/Concurrent/ThreadLocalVar.html) instead of `Thread.current`?

Comment: You might want to include some code example.